# R: permutation in parallel in R (how can to execute this in parallel in R?)

Tags: r, parallel-processing, permutation

I'm killing my laptop with next job every time I run next code.
Need help with optimising performance:

```
library(gtools)
numbers <- as.data.frame(permutations(n = 50, r = 5, v = 1:50))
numbers <- t(apply(numbers,1,sort))
numbers <- numbers[!duplicated(numbers),]
numbers <- as.data.frame(numbers)
```

Comment: Need help with what? What error messages are you getting? What sounds does your laptop make?

Comment: it use all my 16gb, and only use one core.... it doesn't give me any error.

Comment: What error are you talking about?

Comment: my laptop just freeze whe i run this line  t(apply(numbers,1,sort))

Comment: I believe that `combn(50,5)` generates what you want, and doesn't require to optimize the performance.